# Half-Duplex Max485 synchronization issue on Raspberry PI

Tags: c#, serial-port, communication, raspberry-pi4, rs485

I have a Raspberry Pi program written in C#(.NET core). The program communicates on Raspberry Pi UART pins(pin 8,10) through max485 with electronics. When raspberry sends some data to electronics, electronics respond after several ms. Re/De are connected to GPIO 12(pin 32). I have a problem with switching Re/De(GPIO12) I don't know when to switch it. I tried with all delays but for each command is different and it's not 100% precise. Program works on USB port with converter but need to work with UART pins.

```
 void Cct_Send_Receive(int heder, int dlen)
        {
            try
            {
                SerialPort serialport = new SerialPort(serialport_string, 9600);
                controller.Write(12, PinValue.High); // turn on GPIO12(enable transmit mode)
                int dlennovi = dlen;
                int lenghtofbite = dlennovi + 5;
                serialport.Open(); // openserialport

                PripremiPaket(heder, dlen); // make buffer
                Array.Clear(INP_Buffer, 0, INP_Buffer.Length);
                serialport.Write(OUT_Buffer, 0, dlennovi + 5); // SENDING DATA TO ELECTRONICS
                int delay = Convert.ToInt32(lenghtofbite); // Delay is set to lenght of bite
                Thread.Sleep(delay); // Wait
                controller.Write(12, PinValue.Low); // Turn off GPIO12(enable receiver mode)
                CctTalk_Receive(ref serialport); // function for receive
                serialport.Close(); // close serial port
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                INP_Buffer[167] = 56;
                INP_Buffer[99] = 158;
                INP_Buffer[244] = 23;
                INP_Buffer[2] = 34;
            }
        }
        void CctTalk_Receive(ref SerialPort ccTport)
        {
            int INidx = 0;
            long wait;
            ccTport.ReadTimeout = 100;
            wait = 0;

            for (wait = 1; wait <= 25; wait++)
            {
                try
                {

                    INP_Buffer[INidx] = Convert.ToByte(ccTport.ReadByte()); // INP_Buffer is byte[]
                    INidx += 1;
                }
                catch (TimeoutException ex)
                {
                    // Console.WriteLine("ode");
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Your userspace application program executes asynchronously with respect to hardware UART events.   This is not a bare-metal environment.  There's a kernel to abstract the hardware.  If you do try to synchronize, then there will be large time delays (e.g. tens of milliseconds) between UART events and your program's response.  RS485 control needs to be performed in the device driver, and not in userspace.

Comment: Open and close system calls are expensive and time-consuming.  So your program should only open the serial terminal one time at program start, and perform the close at program end.  Do not perform open & close for every Send_Receive operation.

Comment: @sawdust I fixed open/close serial port. Where I can find the Device driver for Raspberry Pi UART?